# Triggering event for unit testing

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js

I am trying to trigger a scroll event inside of my unit test using Mocha running in a browser. I have the following code:

```
describe('Background Change', function() {
  describe('toogleBgHandler()', function() {
  it('should contain toggle-bg when scrollTop is more than 0', function() {
    let html = document.createElement('html');
    var target = [];
    target.push(html);
    let body = document.createElement('body');
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    html.appendChild(body);
    body.appendChild(div);
    document.body.dispatchEvent(new Event("scroll"));
    toggleBgHandler(target, div)
    chai.assert.isTrue(div.classList.contains("toggle-bg"));
  });
  });
});
```

Function I am trying to test:

```
function toggleBgHandler(html, ele) {
        document.addEventListener("scroll", (e) => {
        if (html[0].scrollTop === 0) {
            ele.classList.remove("toggle-bg");
        } else {
            ele.classList.add("toggle-bg");
        }
      });
    }
```

How do I trigger a scroll event for a function that depends on it? I have also tried creating an event object, but that didn't work either. Any pointers would be great.

Comment: Is this test running inside of a browser, or are you using something like `jsdom`?

Comment: @Jacob this test is running in a browser. Updated to clarify.

Comment: Creating an event would be the right thing to do, so it'd be good to see what you attempted so we can figure out why it's not working.

Comment: `scroll` events do not bubble.

Answer (score 1):

Is the scroll event your code is looking for on the *window* or on an _element? If it's on the window, you should be able to dispatch a scroll event like this:

```
window.dispatchEvent(new Event('scroll'));
```

Else, you can do:

```
element.dispatchEvent(new Event('scroll'));
```

[Here's a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wxtojLfk/) demonstrating.

Comment: I just made an update to my code that reflects that change, but it's still not working for me for me some reason.

Comment: In your update, you're dispatching the event _before_ the event listener was added. You'll want to call `toggleBgHandler`, then dispatch the event, then assert.

Comment: I have tried that as well, but it seems like the scroll event isn't being picked up as the code inside of the listener never gets called.